# PHP is inserting two records

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to insert one record to a MySQL database:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$ipcliente = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT
            INTO tbactividad
            (hora,ip,motivo)
            VALUES
            ('$date','$ipcliente','Inicio')") or die(mysql_error());
```

But the final result is that two records are inserted, the field 'hora' which stores the date-time on each record is not the same, there is a +2 or +1  seconds difference.

Any help is welcome,

COMPLETE CODE:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conexion.php');
mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$ipcliente = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT
            INTO tbactividad
            (hora,ip,motivo)
            VALUES
            ('$date','$ipcliente','Inicio')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Quini-Mex CD JUAREZ</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url();
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a"  id="page" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Quini-Mex Juárez</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Bienvenid@s a QUINI-MEX JUAREZ, el nuevo sitio web para sus quinielas de futbol.</p>
      <p>Seleccione su opcion para entrar. </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <ul data-role="listview">
          <li><a href="nuevo_usuario.php" data-ajax="false">SOY UN USUARIO NUEVO</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php" data-ajax="false">USUARIO YA EXISTENTE</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4><img src="imagenes/mex.png" width="35" height="23"> <img src="imagenes/bra.png" width="35" height="23"> <img src="imagenes/cro.png" width="35" height="23"> <img src="imagenes/cmr.png" width="35" height="23"></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Four</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you are executing this sql only once. check your page once again.

Comment: @SatishSharma, yes I am sure, the page has only this piece of PHP on it.

Comment: by providing above code it seems that sql is executing only once. put you complete code here.

Comment: OK, I will update my question adding the complete code, @SatishSharma

Comment: Are you executing the PHP more than once? E.g. using JavaScript in some way, something like that...

Comment: @SatishSharma, already updated, please take a look at my complete code.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I have included all my code in the question.

Comment: include your query in the isset condition. may b that is caused by the page refresh

Comment: i think some of its included jquery tries to reload or resubmit the page.

Comment: It looks like the page is being loaded twice, is there anything causing the page to refresh that you are aware of? Maybe in <?php require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); ?> or your javascripts.

Comment: @mvasco try to remove style `background-image: url();`

Comment: @SatishSharma agreed !

Comment: @mvasco try to remove your jquery file from this page and reload once. may be your jquery loading this page twice.

Comment: @SatishSharma, i don't know, but if I write the url on the browser and Enter, then the difference is 0 sec, if I reload the page, the difference is +1 or +2 secs.

Comment: @SatishSharma, removing the lines body {
    background-image: url();
    background-repeat: repeat;
} solves the problem. Thank you

Comment: Are the dates exactly the same on the two inserts?

Comment: @CullyLarson, yes there is only a difference of +2 or +1 sec., but is solved now, the problem lies on the lines body {
    background-image: url();
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

Comment: @SatishSharma would you mind putting your comment into an answer, I would be glad accepting your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Run Firebug and check in network tab how many requests was sent.

Comment: If your problem is solved, post the solution as an answer and accept it as an answer so that the question does not appear on 'unanswered' lists.

Comment: @PhilipAdler, I think the answer should be posted by SatishSharma, who has given me the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem is seen in your code where as problem can be `your page is reloading twice by something hidden reason`.

you can try some given solutions

1. try to remove style `background-image: url();`
2. try to remove your jquery file from this page and reload once. may be your jquery loading this page twice.

**Note:** I have already commented the this answer. but i am giving this as an answer post so that this question may not be listed in unanswered because OP's problem has been solved as commented below question.

Comment: To confirm that the problem is the `background-image` call, because `url()` without a URL in it loads the current document URL by default. Good spot!